# PL/SQL function compilation errors

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to write a PL/SQL function that takes the name of a player as a parameter and returns the number of matches played in his favorite stadiums.

If the player doesn't exist in the players table, the function should returns -2. If the player exists but he doesn't have any favorite stadium, the function returns -1.

This is what I have:

```
create or replace function favS(pname varchar2) return number
as
    fav_stadium_count number;
begin
    select count(case when favstadiums.stadium = matches.stadium then 1 else null end) into fav_stadium_count
    from favstadiums
    right join players
    on favstadiums.player = players.name
    outer join matches
    on favstadiums.stadium = matches.stadium;
    if (count(case when favstadiums.stadium = matches.stadium then 1 else null end) > 0) then
        return fav_stadium_count;
    end if;
    if players.name is null then
        return -2;
    end if;
    if (count(case when favstadiums.stadium = matches.stadium then 1 else null end) < 1) then
        return -1;
    end if;
end;
```

But I get the following compilation errors:

```
Line 9: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
Line 5: SQL Statement ignored
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Here is the relational diagram of the database if it helps:

[image]

**Edit (for Ted):**

```
create or replace function favS(pname varchar2) return number
as
    fav_stadium_count number;
    vplayername varchar(100);
begin
    select count(case when favstadiums.stadium = matches.stadium then 1 else null end) into fav_stadium_count,
    players.name into vplayername
    from favstadiums
    right join players
    on favstadiums.player = players.name
    left outer join matches
    on favstadiums.stadium = matches.stadium
    where name = pname;
    if (fav_stadium_count > 0) then
        return fav_stadium_count;
    end if;
    if vplayername is null then
        return -2;
    end if;
    if (fav_stadium_count < 1) then
        return -1;
    end if;
end;
```

Comment: I am not sure if this ERD is easier to read than the statement.

Comment: The syntax of your edited query is wrong. You need `SELECT value1, value2 INTO variable1, variable2 FROM ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (count(case when favstadiums.stadium = matches.stadium then 1 else null end) > 0) then
   return fav_stadium_count;
end if;
```

should just be:

```
if (fav_stadium_count > 0) then
   return fav_stadium_count;
end if;
```

As far as the following statement:

```
if players.name is null then
   return -2;
end if;
```

Is also wrong. There is no select statement there either. You should be using some sort of variable like `fav_stadium_count` to store the name you want.

And

```
if (count(case when favstadiums.stadium = matches.stadium then 1 else null end) < 1) then
    return -1;
end if;
```

should become:

```
if (fav_stadium_count < 1) then
    return -1;
end if;
```

Comment: Why can't I use count() instead of sum()?

Comment: wow, what was i thinking!!! dude, if (count(...)) ??? what exactly are you counting? there is no select statement there, it's just an if statement... :)

Comment: Thanks. The part above where you explain that `if players.name is null then...` is wrong. Can you show me an example with code? I'm having trouble understanding how I would do this.

Comment: if by `players.name` you are trying to refer to a `table.column`, that cannot be done from an if statement. `players.name` can only be evaluated against a statement on table `players` such as `select players.name from players where name='Ted'`

Comment: So you need something like `select players.name into vplayername from players where name='Ted'` and then you can do the if statement like `if vplayername  is null then return -2; end if;`. Don't forget to declare `vplayername` right before your `begin` statement.

Comment: I've tried to make the changes (see  under 'Edit for ted' above), but now i'm getting error: `FROM keyword not found where expected`. Any ideas? Thanks for the help.

Comment: shouldn't mix fields with variables, they should be on different lines `select fields into variables` like this: `select count(case when favstadiums.stadium = matches.stadium then 1 else null end), players.name into fav_stadium_count, vplayername`

Comment: you are also missing a `group by` clause otherwise even after correcting the `select into` mess, you'll still be getting errors. so you need to add `group by players.name` at the bottom of your select query

Answer (score 0):

I think it's your joins that have the incorrect syntax. Try: INNER JOIN and LEFT OUTER JOIN. Doing and an outer join without specifying which side has got to be wrong.

Comment: The joins are perfectly fine. `outer join` is a `full outer join` and doesn't need a "side".

Comment: Using your suggestion, it did in fact eliminate the original 2 errors above. I now only have an error with the `if players.name is null then` line. I get the error: `PLS-00357: Table,View Or Sequence reference 'PLAYERS.NAME' not allowed in this context`. Any ideas? thanks

Comment: In your diagram the table name is PLAYER not PLAYERS. Other issues are that you are not using the input variable pname in your query so you are querying all players using a full outer join. Also I don't think your if conditions are going to work, I think you need that logic in your query (see Ted's answer).

Answer (score 0):

As general design advice, I'd say that this schema is missing proper primary keys -- each table should have a numeric id column as it's unwise to rely on uniqueness or immutability of real values such as names.

Then the functionality should be broken out because this code is doing too much in one place. Looking up an id for a player name probably should be in a different function, which can return null if no player is found, or an error could be raised (just as it might be if a null player name was passed to the function).

I would break out the "lookup player" functionality into another function, and if the player name doesn't exist then just return null instead of the player id.

Returning the number of favourite stadiums should then be a matter of returning an integer, 0 or greater, and no need for magic numbers to indicate other conditions.